# Multiple lines of equations on either side of left brace, with alignment

Tags: math-mode, align, braces

How can I insert a left brace over multiple lines on **both** sides of the brace? I made a mockup of what I would like:

[image: mockup]

Requirements:

- I would want to be able to use the alignment character `&` on the equations of either side of the brace, to align them vertically as well.
- Each horizontal line must share the same base line, just like in `\[x\ 1+2y\]`. That is, `x` must have the same base line as `1+2y`.

Ps. The equations I have here don't make sense, but it's for something more complicated that I have in mind.

Here's a pseudo-code / starting code (note this does *not* produce the above picture..)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    1 &+ 2y \\
    3 &+ x
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Zarko I want the `x` to be in line with the `1+2y`, and the `y` to be in line with `3+x`. That only gives me one side of the brace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned} x \\ y \end{aligned}%
    \left\{\begin{aligned}  1 & + 2y \\ 
                            3 & + x \end{aligned}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost, but the first line doesn't seem to be in line on both sides of the brace. That is, `x` seems a little lower than `1+2y`. Also `y` seems a little higher than `3+x`, or are they already in line?

Comment: See the base line between `x` and `1+2y`in this code: `\[x 1+2y\]`

Comment: @ksgj1, see if is now better.

Comment: Thanks for the attempts, Zarko. :) I want to be able to use the alignment tab `&` to align the `+` also (see my pseudocode). If I do so in the `matrix` environment, I'll get unwanted spaces. Also, your current code has a extra `\]` at the end.

Comment: above is my last attempt ...